# Disable Enterprise Mode in IE11 within the code and force the broser to render site in Default Mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, mode

I'm aware, that Enterprise Mode in IE is an emulation of IE8 mode and the goal is to make legacy applications working within IE11 (well, the real goal is to show to the organizations that Windows 10 and IE11 can be adopted as MS is able to handle legacy code without involving numbers of developers to rewrite all web sites to match current standards :-) ). I know this is a setting of IE and IE is controlled by registry/local policy/global policy.

The question is - **is there a way to force browser (from code perspective) to render the web site in Default Mode instead of Enterprise Mode** no matter what GPO says, no matter if web site is/isn't mentioned in Enterprise Mode IE website list?

Let me also ask in different way - **how and what do I need to add/avoid/adjust in the web site code in order to make sure, that this web site is IE11 ready** and does not require any Enterprise Mode (emulation)?

I guess I know the answer but I haven't found any relevant source of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to force IE11 browser to render the site in Standard Mode from code point of view - EM is new feature and it's controlled by GPO (Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list).